# Foreach skips the first element

Tags: java

I have an array and "for each" loop skips the first element of it.

```java
for (int number : nums) {
    System.out.println(nums[number]);
}
```

Output starts from `nums[1]`. What is wrong?

Comment: Your for loop is already iterating over `nums`. In other words, the `number` variable is the _element_ of the `nums` array at a specific index (the index is hidden behind-the-scenes). You then use `nums[number]` which would be equivalent to using `nums[nums[index]]`.

Comment: because, maybe `1` is the first element in `nums`. Please verify..

Comment: Perhaps you want `System.out.println(number);` because `number` is already an element of the array.  You don't need to look it up again.

Comment: What does `nums` look like. Do update that in the question. And as pointed out u're already iterating on `nums` with current element pointed by `number` which is probably what you want. And not access it like `nums[number]`

Comment: is `for (int number : nums) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }` , what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an "enhanced for loop":

```
for (int number : nums) {
    System.out.println(nums[number]);
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    int number = nums[i];
    System.out.println(nums[number]);
}
```

So you using `nums[number]` means you're accessing the array with an index whose value is an *element* of the array. If the element at `nums[0]` is `1` then the first element printed out will be the element at `nums[1]`.

---

Note you probably meant to use:

```
for (int number : nums) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Whether or not this solves your problem completely is difficult to say and would depend on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
 for (int currentNumber : nums) {
        System.out.println(currentNumber);
    }
```

I've tried renaming the variable used in the iteration so it is easier to understand how to print it / manipulate it.

For this reason when you use nums[number] at the 1st iteration you are printing nums[1]

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the array again inside the `for` clause, when that is what the `for` is already doing.

With that in mind, your code should look like this:

```java
for (int number : nums) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

What you were doing is access the array at the position indicated by the value from the array being read.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can get value directly in `number` varible. You won't get index in `number` variable. This is exact solution.

```
for (int number : nums) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```